# Tabs not aligning properly when window is resized smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my tabs look like this (picture 1) at all sizes. However, when I resize my tabs they look like this (picture 2). How can I fix it?
[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/whywymam/86zgeLf1/

My HTML code:

```
<div class="Container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-center">
        <div class="panel-header">
             <h1>Job Category</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img class="logo" src="image/bankinglogo.png" width="180px" >
                <p class="bankingl"> Banking and Finance </p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="logo" src="image/engineerlogo.png" width="180px" >
                <p class="bankingl"> Banking and Finance </p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="logo" src="image/healthcare.png" width="180px" >
                <p class="bankingl">Healthcare</p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="logo" src="image/technicia.png" width="185px" >
                <p class="bankingl">IT</p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="logo" src="image/oilandgas.png" width="200px" >
                <p class="bankingl">Oil and Gas</p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="logo" src="image/retail.png" width="180px" >
                <p class="bankingl">Retail and Hospitality</p>
              </a>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default jobPanel center-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-justified selected">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Job Search</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">PYW</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group name-group">
                                    <label for="keyword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Keyword</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="location" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Location</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Search</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!--end of tab 1-->
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <form class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group name-group">
                                    <label for="keyword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Keyword</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="location" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Location</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Search</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!--end of tab 2-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end of tab content-->
                </div>
                <!-- end of tabbable-->
            </div>
            <!--end panel body-->
        </div>
        <!-- end of formTab -->
    </div>
    <!--end of panel container-->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) The code output you are showing us is different than in the picture. 2) In the JSFiddle the tabs are showing just like you want them to show (they are not breaking into new line if the screen is small)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap takes a mobile-first approach, the code you have provided doesn't show the sign-in and sign-up tabs or fields.

But looking at your HTML markup, I can clearly tell you one thing you're missing.

The classes `.col-sm-*` , `col-md-*` , `col-lg-*`, since Bootstrap is mobile-first the class col-xs-* , is the class that you probably want to be adding to your HTML markup.

So I guess if your markup looks something like :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You got to add the `col-xs-*` clas as well so that at smaller widths (mobile and small device screens), the columns are maintained rather than tiled one after another.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Further reading: [Subtle magic of how the Bootstrap Grid works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works).